# How to check if a db field contains a non breaking space?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb-10.3

I import data from an old DB and want to check in my new db if a field contains a non breaking space somewhere. All solutions I found so far replace it, but I just want to search via sql in my mariaDb if in any row this field does contain the non breaking space.

Searching with like obviously doesn't work e.g.

```
select * from my_table 
where
my_field like "%CHAR(160)%"
```

All solutions I found want to replace like this `REPLACE(The_txt, NCHAR(160), ' ')` but I want to check if I have the problem at all before messing with the db.

Comment: `WHERE LOCATE(CHAR(160), columnname)` or `WHERE INSTR(columnname, CHAR(160))`. LIKE (and especially REGEXP) is excess in this case.

Comment: That works, do you want to post it as an answer?

Comment: It is too base for separate answer. You may create self-answer if you think that this will be useful for another participants - but if so then create detailed answer, with links to Manual reference.

Answer (score 1):

As already answered by @Akina, thanks for your help, the below query helps to find records with non-breaking space -

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE INSTR(<column_name>, CHAR(160));
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE LOCATE(CHAR(160), <column_name>);
```